# Regarding text placement with css in chrome

Tags: css

```
HERE <
           not here<
```

---

If the above illustration was a html  or bar and I needed to place text in the upper left corner denoted with HERE<...(and not just to the left side..indicated 
with.....not here <  ), then what css statement accomplishes this.?

Comment: Does `position: absolute: top:0; left:0;` do the trick?

Comment: I mean, you probably have some margin or padding on your `body` or something.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more
research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use *flex* for you to achieve this. Example:

```css
.container{
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
justify-content:flex-start;
}

.container span {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>my text here</span>
</div>
```

Additional scenarios,

•Upper Center:
   align-items: flex-start;
   justify-content:center;

•Upper Right:
   align-items: flex-start;
   justify-content: flex-end;

•Middle Left:
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: flex-start;

•Middle Center:
   align-items: center;
   justify-content:center;

•Middle Right:
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: flex-end;

•Lower Left:
   align-items: flex-end;
   justify-content: flex-start;

•Lower Center:
   align-items: flex-end;
   justify-content: center;

•Lower Right:
   align-items: flex-end;
   justify-content: flex-end;